# fetchAPI not returning response as then() is getting skipped

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am using fetchAPI to do a post call to my router which will fetch data of logged in user.

Below is the code for the same

```
submit_button.addEventListener('click',getuser)

function getuser()
{
console.log('clicked')

const username=uname_button.value;
const password=age_button.value;
console.log('username'+username)
console.log('password'+password)
 const user = {
    email: username,
    password: password

};
  let options = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user)
  }

fetch('/users', options)
  .then(function(response) {
  console.log(response)
  })

}
```

When i execute this in browser, data is getting posted successfully but response is not getting printed , not even promise. 
when i added debug points, i could see that control is not going inside then() block? 
Can anyone help me with how how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

add a catch block after then to see if any error occurred, as follows:

```
fetch('/users', options)
    .then(function(response) { console.log(response) })
    .catch(function(error) { console.log(error) })
```

Comment: I have added catch bock as well, but from fetch method, control is directly going to end ignoring then and catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that fetch returns a Promise containing the Response object. In order to extract the JSON body content from the response, we use the json() method.

```
fetch('/users', options)
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then(data => console.log(data))
 .catch((error) => {
   console.error('Error:', error);
 });
```

Comment: After adding catch block, it is now throwing below error.                                      
TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestContent' of undefined. I have checked myserver and it is creating a record in db but unable to fetch the response

Comment: Try with this
 headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }